# What's the difference between "export" and "setenv"?

Tags: environment-variables

What's the difference between `export` and `setenv`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

there is none but:

`setenv` is the name of the command in the *csh family of shells

`export` is the name of the command in the "other" family of shells (ash, bourne, bourne again, zsh)

and, ok, the syntax is slightly different. but other than that? none.

Comment: Are we allowed to consider that bastard c-shell syntax from Berkeley "deprecated" yet?

Comment: no: http://www.tcsh.org/Welcome

Comment: it's good to be aware that in bourne (unlike bash) you can't do `export VARIABLE=VALUE`. Instead you need to do 
```VARIABLE=VALUE\n
export VARIABLE
```