# What is the difference between env, setenv, export and when to use?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

Recently I noticed we have 3 options to set environment variables:

1. `export envVar1=1`
2. `setenv envVar2=2`
3. `env envVAr3=3`

If there are other ways, please enlighten us.

When should I prefer one over the other? Please suggest guidelines.

As for shell compatibility, which is the most expansive (covers more shell dialects)?

I already noticed this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8592/whats-the-difference-between-export-and-setenv) but I wish to expand the question with `env` and usage preference guidelines.

Answer (score 48):

`export VARIABLE_NAME='some value'` is the way to set an environment variable in any POSIX-compliant shell (`sh`, `dash`, `bash`, `ksh`, etc.; also zsh). If the variable already has a value, you can use `export VARIABLE_NAME` to make it an environment variable without changing its value.

Pre-POSIX [Bourne shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) did not support this, which is why you'll see scripts that avoid `export VARIABLE_NAME='some value'` and use `VARIABLE_NAME='some value'; export VARIABLE_NAME` instead. But pre-POSIX Bourne shells are extremely rare nowadays.

`setenv VARIABLE_NAME='some value'` is the csh syntax to set an environment variable. `setenv` does not exist in sh, and csh is extremely rarely used in scripts and has been surpassed by bash for interactive use for the last 20 years (and zsh for even longer), so you can forget about it unless you encounter it.

The `env` command is very rarely useful except in [shebang lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability). When invoked without arguments, it displays the environment, but `export` does it better (sorted, and often quoted to disambiguate newlines in values from newlines that separate values). When invoked with arguments, it runs a command with extra environment variables, but the same command without `env` also works (`VAR=value mycommand` runs `mycommand` with `VAR` set to `value`, just like `env VAR=value mycommand`). The reason `env` is useful in shebang line is that it performs `PATH` lookup, and it happens to not do anything else when invoked with a command name. The `env` command can be useful to run a command with only a few environment variables with `-i`, or without parameters to display the environment including variables with invalid names that the shell doesn't import.

Answer (score 9):

Setting a variable like `VAR='asdf'` leaves environment unmodified, meaning that the programs you launch in the same session will know nothing about `VAR` and will be unable to access it. You want this behaviour when writing shell scripts.

`export`, on the other hand, is a bash builtin that modifies the environment thus making the exported variable visible for child processes spawned in the current session. You can achieve the same by running `VAR='asdf' %program_name%`.

`env` is not a builtin, but a program by itself. On the surface it works exactly like when you `VAR='asdf' %program_name%`, but at the lower level things get a little more complicated. First, the `env` gets launched. It modifies environment, then executes the command with given arguments. The same behaviour you can acheive in your own code by using [exec(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) system call.

`setenv` is just `export` in csh-family shells, as stated in your answer.

Comment: In modern shells, `VAR=asdf` does update the environment if `VAR` was already in the environment. (This wasn't true in the original Bourne shell.)

Answer (score 3):

There are several questions with answers that answers this:

- [Trying to understand .bashrc, env, and export](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268253/trying-to-understand-bashrc-env-and-export)
- [Difference between shell variables which are exported and those which are not in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-environment-variables-and-exported-environment-variables-in-b)
- [What is the difference in usage between shell variables and environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363525/what-is-the-difference-in-usage-between-shell-variables-and-environment-variable)
- [bash setenv command is not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85099/bash-setenv-command-is-not-found)
- [What's the difference between "export" and "setenv"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8592/80216)

(etc.)