# How to set multiple env variables?

Tags: environment-variables, set

I have to set 10 env variables (setenv). I saved all these env variable in a `filename.env`. Is there a way to set all the variable inside the file with single command ?

I tried with "source filename.env", variables are getting set but many other things are also happening. Doubt what I did is wrong. Please help.

**Edit:**
content of filename.env:

```
setenv variable1 value1
setenv variable2 value2
.
.
setenv variable10 value10
```

Comment: What’s in the file and what, exactly, are the “many other things?”

Comment: Why not add the content of your `.env` file to your question?

Comment: What shell are you using? csh?

Comment: using cshc @ilkkachu

Answer (score 3):

**in bash:**

With the following file `~/variables.rc`:

```
export test1="test1"
export test2="test2"
export test3="test3"
export test4="test4"
export test5="test5"
```

You can source the file. Those sourced variables are then known in your terminal session:

```
[ws] user ~ >source variables.rc  
[ws] user ~ >echo $test3
test3
```

---

**in csh:**

With the following file `~/variables.rc`:

```
setenv test1 test10
setenv test2 test20
setenv test3 test30
setenv test4 test40
setenv test5 test50
```

You can source the file. Those sourced variables are then known in your terminal session:

```
[ws] user ~ >source variables.rc  
[ws] user ~ >echo $test3
test30
```

Comment: if "setenv" instead of "export" same working ?

Comment: It depends on your shell: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368944/what-is-the-difference-between-env-setenv-export-and-when-to-use

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using cshc @kevin

Comment: Saved my days, in a project I got about 15 variables :D